# Wood material does not align with axes to look like planks

Tags: texturing, materials, node-editor

[image: A small traditional German house]

I followed a tutorial to make a wood material and made the settings so that it would look like planks on the house.

The material here, however, looks diagonal when it should be horizontal. There were two materials made for the vertical direction and horizontal direction I created two plane objects and applied the respective materials on each and they looked just fine.

I tried adjusting the Mapping node on the house but I could not rotate it. I do not know if there is an easier way to do this and would appreciate tips.

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/275819/how-would-i-automatically-not-stretch-textures-to-already-made-objects/275823#275823) will help you.

Comment: Thanks. Adding the Empty object solved the problem.

Comment: ..or [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/170172/35559), for procedural 3D wood